# Sufficient or necessary conditions for dominance of expectation of min(c, random-variable)

Tags: probability-theory

If $D$ and $D'$ are non-negative random variables, what are sufficient and/or necessary conditions for $E[D] \geq E[D']$ to imply $E[\min(c,D)]\geq E[\min(c,D')]$ for
any $c\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is difficult to discern what is being asked here, one might be concerned with the identities
$$
D=\int_0^{+\infty}[D\geqslant x]\cdot\mathrm dx
\quad\text{and}\quad
\min(c,D)=\int_0^{c}[D\geqslant x]\cdot\mathrm dx,
$$
which yield
$$
\mathrm E(D)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm P(D\geqslant x)\cdot\mathrm dx
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathrm E(\min(c,D))=\int_0^{c}\mathrm P(D\geqslant x)\cdot\mathrm dx.
$$